# Is it a good idea to use classes just to maintain few constant variables

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I came across a code for logging mechanism in which based on severity the messages are printed.
So, if the severity is set to 0 then print DEBUG logs, if 1000 then print only INFO logs etc. etc.

```
class Logs
{
public:
    static const int DEBUG=0;
    static const int INFO=1000;
    static const int SOMETHING_ELSE=2000;
}
```

That's it in the class. Nothing else.
And instead of using values as it is, the variables are used.
Example : If i wanted to pass severity to some helper function then instead of passing 1000 as its argument it passes `Logs::INFO.`

My question is that why do we really need a class just to define these const variables.
We could have used enums as well. Or Macros. Or const global variables. Or const variables inside namespaces. But why classes? Are there any advantages of using classes over the other options that i mentioned?

Is it just matter of choice to use one over the other or one has a concrete advantage over the others?

Comment: An enum makes a lot more sense here.

Comment: Perhaps to give a sense that `INFO` is logically connected to `Logs`

Comment: Deleisha, if thats the case then you could change the naming convention itself during the design phase. Instead of DEBUG and INFO and some XYZ variables, you could change it to loggerDebug, loggerInfo and loggerXyz respectively. But keeping it in class and declaring them static const is something i cudnt understand

Answer (score 1):

> We could have used `enum`s as well.

That would have been my first choice, an `enum` defined in the scope of `Log`.

> Or Macros.

Absolutely not. Macros are inferior to integral variables for many reasons.

> Or const global variables.

Not as bad as macros but they should not be the first choice.

> Or const variables inside namespaces.

That's also a possibility. Even here, I would recommend using an `enum`.

> But why classes?

The choice between an `enum` or integral constants defined in the scope of a class or in the scope of a `namespace` is not always clear to me. You have to make a judgement call based on what those numbers represent. In this case, it seems OK to me to use:

```
class Logs
{
   public:
    enum MessageType {DEBUG=0, INFO=1000, SOMETHING_ELSE=2000};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to disagree with Akhil that using `#define` is a good idea, for a number of different reasons, not the least of which are type safety and the potential for subsequent code to redefine the value.

If the intent is to limit access to these constants (or to make it convenient for subclasses to access them), then including them in a class is certainly an option, but if you plan to keep them public then I think using a class is probably not your best choice.

I'd consider trying namespaces - namespaces have the advantage of not polluting the global namespace and can be used with similar syntax (including `using` statements and `::` syntax), but since a namespace is not a class few would assume that the values are associated with a particular object... That may help others understand your intent.

You can also use enum, as noted above, but that would only work for integer values. There is another advantage to simply declaring the values - you could declare them externally, in case you want to actually define the value in another file.

```
namespace NyNamespace {
     const int kMyValue = 5; // Can be referenced as MyNamespace::kMyValue, or benefit from a 'using' statement.
     extern const int kDefinedElsewhere; // Can be declared here and defined elsewhere.
     const float kMyFloatValue = 5.f; // Not limited to integers.
     enum {
         kMyEnumValue = 5 // Limited to integer values.
     };
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You  can use it like if u want to get global access

```
#define DEBUG 0
#define INFO 1000
#define SOMETHING_ELSE 2000


void functioncall_2(int)
{
   //do something
}

//function call will be
functioncall_2(DEBUG);
```

Or

```
enum LOG {
    DEBUG,
    INFO = 1000,
    SOMETHING_ELSE = 2000,
} 

void functioncall_1(LOG)
{
    //do something
}

//function call will be
functioncall_1(DEBUG); // u can call it like LOG::DEBUG or DEBUG in the case of enum.
```

Better way as per my opinion

Comment: Using `#define` should be the last choice in C++, used only if you really must do something which can't be done using other ways. And in this particular case, using `#define` seems particularly bad, as such common names as `DEBUG` and `INFO` are very like to have clashes.